# Laravel nl2br not getting foreach parameters properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, nl2br

So i am currently working with nl2br. I don't know whether this is a bug, or a wrong way to doing things from my side but i encounter this. First of all, here's the snippet :

```
@foreach($dataList as $data)
    <div class="productDesc">
        {!! nl2br(e($data->product->description)) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

When i run this, the output is only the description of the first product. I initially thought there's something wrong with my code but when i do a debug like this :

```
@foreach($dataList as $data)
    {{ $data->id }}
    <div class="productDesc">
        {{ $data->id }}
        {!! nl2br(e($data->product->description)) !!}
    </div>
    {{ $data->id }}
@endforeach
```

The result in the 2nd row is :

```
2
1 This is a description for 1st product
2
```

As you can see, it somehow ignore the forwhile loop parameter. Can someone inform whether there's a solution for this or am i just code it wrongly ?

Comment: What about defining it like `@foreach($dataList->product as $data)` ?

Comment: set your controller code which render the view

Comment: @BKF can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Norgul i can't do that because aside from that productDesc div, there are also a ton of other views that needs parameters from $datalist. I only put the snippet of the description section above.

Comment: I mean the code you prepare dataList

Comment: @VincentTiara then make a double 'for' loop. Set the inner one to `$data->product as $product`, and then call by `$product->description`